# .closest() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list:

```
<div id="saved">
    <ul class="list-group" style="display: block;">
        <li class="marked list-group-item">box-shadow:<span class="marked_text">0px 0px rgb(200,200,200)</span>;<a class="pull-right multiple-shadows checkbox-active">Click</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to store the text that is inside  inside a variable.

I have written the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", "#saved ul li > a.multiple-shadows", function () {

    $(this).toggleClass("checkbox-active");

    var roll = $(this).closest("span").text();
    console.log(roll);
});
```

The problem is that with .text() i get an empty value and with .html() i get undefined.Any ideas?

Comment: console log your `this` and see what it's pointing to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.closest()` gets the parent (https://api.jquery.com/closest/). What you need is `$(this).siblings("span")`. Also try to limit the number of selectors in jQuery. `$('a.multiple-shadows')` is more than enough.

EDIT: if you have more than one span siblings, to get the first one, use `$(this).siblings("span").first()`

Answer (score 2):

`closest` finds the closest ancestor of an element. the `span` is a sibling of your `a` tag, so `closest` is correct to return `undefined`. your a is inside of an `li`, which is inside of a `ul`, which is inside of a `div`, so those are the only elements that `closest` will return anything for.

Answer (score 1):

Since your span come before the `a` tag, you simple can use the `.prev()` function.

```
$(this).toggleClass("checkbox-active");
var roll = $(this).prev().text();
console.log(roll);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hp9or7pf/

Answer (score 1):

`.closest` "matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree" (https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Therefore, `.closest` will not match any siblings but ancestors. Instead, you can use `.prev()`.

```
$("#saved").on("click", ".multiple-shadows",function(){

    $(this).toggleClass("checkbox-active");

    var roll=$(this).prev().text();
    alert(roll);
});
```